# Moving a window of a program using C++?

Tags: c++, window

Is there a way to move a window of a program (lets say uTorrent or Acrobat) using a C++ code?
Can C++ or C maybe, control an application window?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: What OS do you want to target? It's possible, but Windows, Linux, OS X (etc.) will each require a somewhat different solution.